# How to workout on a bad day

Tags: bodybuilding, sleep, motivation, pre-workout

I've slept only 5 hours and slept poorly due to anger ans stress. 
Today feels like a bad day and I feel like I have no energy and im not motivated. 
I do workout 6 days a week, but what can I do physically and mentally to boost myself up today and give the best even if I still feel tired?

Comment: Relax today and do something to take yourself off the stress? Or go swimming? :)

Comment: But, i want and need to workout.

Comment: Well, you can start with something fun to get you in the mood. If you swim for 30 mins, you ought to be in a better mood and frame of mind. Or go running. Or simply discard your feelings and do it anyway. :)

Comment: You may want to go back to the reason why you do workouts, and if that reason is more important than how you feel right now. If it is, you do the workout. You don't have to like it, just do it without thinking so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are already angry then use that. Aggression can be a brilliant tool in the weight room to induce adrenaline. You would be amazed at what you can do in the gym when you are pissed off. Don't stay angry forever though, use it as a stress release to calm yourself and set you up for the day. It really can work wonders.

Answer (score 2):

I rate my training days on a scale of 1-4.  This helps me address what I need to do.  First the scale:

1. I'm trash.  No energy, very diminished capability.
2. The bad side of average.  Shouldn't have too many of these.
3. The good side of average.  Most training days should be here.
4. I'm superman.  Nothing can stop me, better than normal capability.

The 1 days and the 4 days should be pretty spread apart.  However, if you actually hit a 1 day, the most productive thing you can do is take the day off and get some rest.  If you absolutely must train, do something very light weight to get your blood moving.  Perhaps just make it a light cardio day and go home.

On a 2 day, just back off the assistance work a bit to help you recover.  On a 3 day just train per normal.  You can really push yourself on a 4 day, but expect a couple 2 days after that.